# Index a numpy array with another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I feel silly, because this is such a simple thing, but I haven't found the answer either here or anywhere else.

Is there no straightforward way of indexing a numpy array with another?

Say I have a 2D array

```
>> A = np.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [5, 6],
   [7, 8]])
```

if I want to access element [3,1] I type

```
>> A[3,1]
8
```

Now, say I store this index in an array

```
>> ind = np.array([3,1])
```

and try using the index this time:

```
>> A[ind]
array([[7, 8],
       [3, 4]])
```

the result is not A[3,1]

The question is: having arrays A and ind, what is the simplest way to obtain A[3,1]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a tuple:

```
>>> A[(3, 1)]
8
>>> A[tuple(ind)]
8
```

The `A[]` actually calls the special method `__getitem__`:

```
>>> A.__getitem__((3, 1))
8
```

and using a comma creates a tuple:

```
>>> 3, 1
(3, 1)
```

Putting these two basic Python principles together solves your problem.

You can store your index in a tuple in the first place, if you don't need NumPy array features for it.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of solution I was hoping for!

Answer (score 5):

That is because by giving an array you actually ask

```
A[[3,1]]
```

Which gives the third **and** first index of the 2d array instead of the first index of the third index of the array as you want.

You can use

```
 A[ind[0],ind[1]]
```

You can also use (if you want more indexes at the same time);

```
A[indx,indy]
```

Where `indx` and `indy` are numpy arrays of indexes for the first and second dimension accordingly.

See here for all possible indexing methods for numpy arrays: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html